# Change tooltip location with HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I got some CSS3 code from a site which gives a nice tooltip box when hovering over an anchor element (`<a>`). However, the tooltip always appears to the upper, right of the `<a>`. If the anchor is at the top of the screen, the tooltip is off the top edge of the browser, and if the anchor is at the right edge of the screen, then the tooltip appears off the right side of the browser. In either case, I can't see the bulk of the tooltip. Is there a way to dynamically have the tooltip appear in a visible area of the screen based on how close to the edge of the screen the anchor is?

Here is the CSS and a sample anchor:

```
.tooltip {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #0077AA;
    color: #0077AA;
    cursor: help;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color: #0099CC;
}

.tooltip:after {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFF;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    margin-top: -24px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.htooltip, .htooltip:visited, .tooltip:active {
    color: #0077AA;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.htooltip:hover {
    color: #0099CC;
}

.htooltip span {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: -75px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.htooltip:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a class="htooltip" href="#">WA &mdash; Washington
 <span>Washington State is the northwesternmost state in the contiguous 48.</span>
</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's a first whack at my solution, in case it might be helpful to someone:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .htooltip, .htooltip:visited, .tooltip:active
        {
            color: #0077AA;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .htooltip:hover
        {
            color: #0099CC;
        }

        .htooltip span
        {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
            border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: #fff;
            opacity: 0;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
            position: absolute;
            text-decoration: none;
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 350px;
            z-index: 10;

            -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, visibility 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }

        .htooltip:hover span
        {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
        }
    </style>


<a onmouseover="SetTopLeft(this);" class="htooltip" href="#">WA &mdash; Washington<span>Washington State is the northwesternmost state in the contiguous 48.</span></a>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetTopLeft(obj) {
            var mouseX = $(obj).offset().left;
            var mouseY = $(obj).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            var screenWidth = $(window).width();
            var screenHeight = $(window).height();

            var top;
            var left;

            // If the tooltip would be too close to the top of the browser, show it below the element.
            if (screenHeight - mouseY > screenHeight - 50)
            {
                top = mouseY + 17;
            }
            else
            {
                top = mouseY - 60;
            }

            if (screenWidth - mouseX < 350 && mouseX < 350) // Close to the left and the right - center the span over the element.
            {
                left = mouseX / 2;
            }
            else if (screenWidth - mouseX < 350) // Close to the right - put span to the left.
            {
                left = mouseX - 350;
            }
            else
            {
                left = mouseX + 50; // Close to the left with extra space on the right - put span to the right.
            }

            $(obj).find("span").css("top", top);
            $(obj).find("span").css("left", left);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: nope, you can't do that without JS

Comment: But there are numerous tooltip libraries and it's easy to code one.

Comment: So it would be a matter of doing something like: get mouse cursor position, get screen width, see if I'm near a browser edge, then assign the appropriate CSS class to the element?

Comment: I think it is possible after the edit. Nice code by the way I never saw that option. See also my try for a solution.

Comment: Added a possible solution above.

Answer (score 1):

See this [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/xEdvC/). I added these few lines:

```
.htooltip span {
    position: relative;
    top: 6em;
    left: 5em;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: If there's space above the anchor, then the tooltip doesn't stay "attached" to it. Also, it won't pop over to the left if the anchor is near the right edge of the screen. I think I'll have to give the javascript solution a try. Seems like it will probably give the best result. Thanks.